# Cocoa NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

i have a problem with accessing value from the NSTExtField in different class here is the code:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;   
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *numberOfPhrases; 

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize numberOfPhrases;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[numberOfPhrases stringValue]);
}
```

TestClass.h

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;

@end
```

TestClass.m

```
@implementation TestClass

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {


    NSLog(@"%@",[numberOfPhrases stringValue]); ????????? 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't access the text field value in another class without a link to it.

To access the text field's value you either need to have one more IBOutlet to it in this class or an IBOutlet to AppDelegate so that you can access its property.

TestClass.h

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
{
     IBOutlet NSTextField *numberOfPhrases;   // connect it to the new referencing outlet of text field by dragging a NSObject object in your xib and setting its class to "TestClass"
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;

@end
```

OR an another option is to have a IBOutlet of AppDelegate in TestClass (because if you only create a new instance of AppDelegate and not its IBOutlet then a different instance of text field will be created and you will not be able to access the value of your text field)

TestClass.h

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
{
     IBOutlet AppDelegate *appDel;   // connect in the xib
}

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;

@end
```

TestClass.m

```
@implementation TestClass : NSObject

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    [[appDel numberOfPhrases]stringValue]; //get the string value in text field
}

@end
```

Comment: thx for reply and sorry for missing code parts (this should be written in pseudo-code)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you're missing is the addition to your TestClass.m file:

```
#import "TestClass.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation TestClass

- (IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *theInstance = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [theInstance numberOfPhrases];

}

@end
```

You need to include the class header of `AppDelegate.h` in `TestClass.m`, then you simply call an instance through `[[AppDelegate alloc] init];` You'll need to link your `NSTextField` to the **Sent Actions** in Interface Builder `do:Something -> TestClass` and **Referencing Outlets** `numberOfPhrases -> AppDelegate`.

**Output**:

```
2014-01-21 23:32:56.499 test[6236:303] Wonders Never Cease
```

Comment: I would like to get the value from the textfiled which is initialized inside AppDelegate.Do i have to instantiate AppDelegate inside TestClass ?

Comment: @crazyjuice, Missing the point would be having code that does not run - if you have mistakes they need to be corrected before going any further.